# Is there a way to launch a python script as a apk without seeing the code first without encapsulating the script inside the apk?

Tags: python, android, apk

I'm a student and got the opportunity to write a python program set for a friend's company's production area. It is basically several math functions with error checking and a menu. Finished the program and it works well, but I have one concern.
The program needs to be scalable, which I have built in templates to do so.
The problem I have right now is its only launchable via an IDE.
I don't want the workers to see the code, and accidently break the code when launching.
But I also don't want to compile the code into an apk, as it needs to be easily changeable.

So my question is thus:  is there any way to make an apk that just launches the core script, brings up a python console and loads it's dependencies from a file structure that can easily be accessed by something like qPython without first showing the code to the user?

The reason this is necessary, is the people in charge who will write new programs only know qPython and program stuff as if it were fortran, adding a layer of something like Android Studio might make it where they never remember how to update their program, thus never do so.
Everywhere I look there is only options pull the whole script into an apk.

Thanks in advance for the input.

So tl:dr looking for a method to have push button run python console script on a android, if it exists.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question has a few contradictory constraints: "[currently] only launchable via an IDE", "don't want the workers to see the code", "don't want to compile the code into an apk" and "easily changeable [by company devs]". Any app that you don't want users to see/edit will either be compiled or run on server-side. As you get further into software dev thinking [and getting sign-off from management] about the trade-offs before writing any code is desirable.

Comment: Clarification: Is there a way to make an icon run a python console script run on an android without encapsulating the script and it's dependencies in an apk and skip the step of seeing editable code? This is a stand alone program written for non networked android tablets as a replacement for ti-83 calculators.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. A stand alone program doesn't need a third-party runtime environment (IDE/Python). Android runs APKs, generally no different than a Windows PC running an EXE file (but Android is its own thing, e.g. files are handled differently for security issues). Android has no built-in interpreter for writing & running code, unlike TI-83. Custom program would still need to be installed. Writing for mobile is different than writing for command line, and has a different UI/UX experience (typing is harder than pressing buttons). See the free tutorials on Android development online.